# Does putting intermediary math results into variables improve performance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization

I have been playing around with the Riemann zeta function.
I want to optimize execution time as much as possible here so I put the intermediary results in temporary variables. But testing revealed that I get no performance boost from this. At least not noticeably.

```
function zeta(z, limit){
    var zres = new Complex(0, 0);

        for(var x = 1; x <= limit; x++){
            var ii = z.imaginary * Math.log(1/x);
            var pp = Math.pow(1/x, z.real);
            zres.real += pp * Math.cos(ii);
            zres.imaginary += pp * Math.sin(ii);
        }

    return zres;
}
```

My question is: Even though I couldn't measure a difference in execution time, what's theoretically faster? Calculating ii and pp once and handing them over as variables, or calculating them twice and not wasting time with the declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting things in (local) variables on its own will usually not have a major effect on performance. If anything it *could* increase the pressure on the register allocator (or equivalent) and slightly reduce performance.

Avoiding calculating expressions multiple times by putting the result into a local variable *can* improve performance **if** the just-in-time compiler (or runtime) isn't smart enough to do the equivalent optimization (i.e. compute the value only once and re-use the computation result each times the expression is used).

There's really no universally applicable rule here. You need to benchmark and optimize on the specific system you want best performance on.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language, it isn't compiled so every operation is called each time you write it

Comment: @DDomen: that statement is misleading at best and wrong in many cases. Almost all modern JavaScript runtimes include a just in time compiler and they *do* execute various optimizations (and many of them are similar to what traditional compilers do).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any specific source on how javascript engines exactly handle this?

Comment: I do not. It's usually hard to find the *specific* code and/or description of what a compiler/runtime does here, because this tends to involve lots of overlapping and interacting optimizations and is usually hard to grasp. The V8 folks (the engine behind node.js and Chrome) have blog posts/videos explaining many of their optimizations, so you might want to start looking in this direction to get a grasp of the kind of stuff they do.

Comment: Upvote for the JIT compiler, but I think most of the complex expressions are just type evaluated, you can not simplify functions calls because they can have side effects. `Math` functions **maybe** are simplifiable (sort of const functions), but I would not rely on the JIT for measure speed since it can vary from an enviroment to another.

Comment: @DDomen: math calls having intrinsics (and thus being known-side-effect-free) is a fairly basic optimization that I expect to be pretty common. But I agree that one should never *depend* on something like that being optimized and simply measure the actual performance on the desired target platform(s) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Instanciating a variable is surely faster then a math operation (like `Math.log` or `Math.pow`) so it is better to instantiate them. If you want to prevent the local scope of the `for` to waste some very little less time due to the variable initializzation and collection you can declare `pp` and `ii` out of the loop. This is a quite ridiculous time in respect of all the other operations.

```js
function zeta(z, limit){
    var zres = new Complex(0, 0);
    var ii, pp;

    for(var x = 1; x <= limit; x++){
      ii = z.imaginary * Math.log(1/x);
      pp = Math.pow(1/x, z.real);
      zres.real += pp * Math.cos(ii);
      zres.imaginary += pp * Math.sin(ii);
    }

    return zres;
}
```